# How to compute digamma function in complex numbers in order to use this function in Tensorflow(to accept input as a tensor)?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, complex-numbers, gamma, jax

```python
N= [-7.12843079e+02, -1.39668296e+02, -6.01626070e+01, -3.51688015e+01]
jax.scipy.special.digamma(N)
```

```
TypeError: digamma does not accept dtype complex64. Accepted dtypes are subtypes of floating.
```

I'm trying to compute digamma in complex numbers using jax.scipy.special.digamma, however, it still gives me this error even though the doc of this package says it can be complex
here is what the doc says:

Parameters:
z (array_like) – Real or complex argument.

Any idea how to solve this issue? Or is there an alternative way such as other library or other packages that allows me to use the complex number to compute the digamma function!?

Comment: Unfortunately, JAX does not currently implement any flavors of gamma functions for complex types, because the XLA implementation it is based on does not accept complex types. A related issue is here: https://github.com/google/jax/issues/6765

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. This is how I solved it. THE LONG WAY. I know someone will give a concise way of doing it.

From the definition [psi function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jrkF.gif)

I used the Gamma function from [here](https://literateprograms.org/gamma_function_with_the_lanczos_approximation__python_.html). MAKE SURE THE OUTPUT IS IN JAX ELSE YOU WONT BE ABLE TO USE GRAD;

```
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax import grad

def gamma_func_numeric(z):
    g = 7
    z -= 1
    x = lanczos_coef[0]

    for i in range(1, g+2):
        x +=   lanczos_coef[i]/(z+i)    
        t = z + g  + 0.5
   return jnp.sqrt(2*jnp.pi)*jnp.power(t,(z+0.5))*jnp.exp(-t)*x

eta is a complex number

def psi_numeric(eta):
    gamma_prime = grad(gamma_func_numeric, holomorphic=True)(eta)
    gamma = gamma_func_numeric(eta)
    return gamma_prime/gamma
```

Lets compare our results:

```
scipy.special.psi(1.+2j)=(0.7145915153739777+1.3208072826422304j)

psi_numeric(1.+2j) = DeviceArray(0.7145916+1.3208078j, dtype=complex64)
```